# Intellij classpath error Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, classpath

The directories of the Intellij project:

```
src/main/java/rewards/testdb/schema.sql
src/main/java/rewards/testdb/test-data.sql
src/main/java/rewards/testdb/config/alternate-datasource-config.xml
src/main/java/rewards/testdb/config/AlternateDataSourceConfigTests.java
```

The bean configuration under test (from alternate-datasource-config.xml):

```
<bean id="dataSource-createdFromList" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="databaseName" value="rewards" />
    <property name="databasePopulator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator">
            <property name="scripts">
                <util:list>
                    <value>classpath:rewards/testdb/schema.sql</value>
                    <value>classpath:rewards/testdb/test-data.sql</value>
                </util:list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm encountering an error in my unit test:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [rewards/testdb/schema.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
```

**However, if I modified the directories to:**

```
src/main/java/rewards/testdb/config/schema.sql
src/main/java/rewards/testdb/config/test-data.sql
src/main/java/rewards/testdb/config/alternate-datasource-config.xml
src/main/java/rewards/testdb/config/AlternateDataSourceConfigTests.java
```

**and modify my bean config:**

```
<bean id="dataSource-createdFromList" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="databaseName" value="rewards" />
        <property name="databasePopulator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator">
                <property name="scripts">
                    <util:list>
                        <value>classpath:rewards/testdb/config/schema.sql</value>
                        <value>classpath:rewards/testdb/config/test-data.sql</value>
                    </util:list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**...my test passes.**

*Why?*

Comment: You should put the resources in `src\main\resources`. Xml files won't be copied to the class path otherwise.

Comment: Then why does it pass in the second?

Answer (score 1):

In your idea project configuration, point target path as your projects target folder: Edit Configurations->Deployment->Edit Artifact(Click on pencil icon)-> set "Output Directory" input as "your_project_folder_path/target "
Then whenever you edit jdbc.properties file, this will take effect with a restart.

This is valid for maven web projects.

Answer (score 0):

Spring will interpret the resource references as relative (to your test class). You should always make sure to use absolute paths in your resource references, i.e.:

```
<value>classpath:/rewards/testdb/schema.sql</value>
<value>classpath:/rewards/testdb/test-data.sql</value>
```

(note the initial forward slash in the resource specifications)

Comment: It really shouldn't matter, but it might since you're doing this from inside the IDE: Have you tried moving the resources to the correct directories: `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources`?